# Henry's Law and "Gases in Vapour Phase"

Tags: solutions

I found the following definition of Henry's Law in my textbook:

> "The partial pressure of the **gas in vapour phase** is proportional to the mole fraction of the gas in the solution."

My questions:
(a) Why should the undissolved gas be in vapour phase?

(b) As i understand it, a gas is called a vapour if it is below its critical temperature.

(c) But from other sources on the Internet (such as Wikipedia )there is no such restriction on the temperature for Henry's law to hold[I mean the temperature is not supposed to be below the critical temperature of gas to use Henry's law].

(d) Can a gas above it's critical temperature be dissolved in a liquid?

P.S:
(a) I am having trouble understanding why the word vapour phase is used in the definition. Although I do understand what Henry's Law is trying to say.

(b) I tried to search all over the internet but could not find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Rather vapour/gas in gaseous phase.//1 Why should not ? //2 + usually if it is possibnle to have it as liqiud at give circumstances as well // 3 no such restiction // Even helium with crit. T few K dissolves in liquids

Comment: @Poutnik [1]I have no problem with the gas being a vapour but stating explicitly in the definition means that if it is not a vapour then we can't use the Henry's law and that is what bugs me.  [2] I can't find a satisfactory example of helium being dissolved in liquid at a temperature above its critical temperature on the net ; please clarify.

Comment: Henry's law is explictly about dissolving of gas in supposedly nonvolatile solvent. This law is closely related to the Raoult law, considering volatile liquid components and their vapours. // What example do you need ? All gases dissolve in liquids, regardless of their critical temperature, just their Henry constants differ.

Comment: @Poutnik [1]So the definition in the book (or rather the phrase "gas in vapour phase") is unnecessary? [2] I am confused as to why the word "vapour phase" has been used...(pls see ques part a,b and c)...[3]Any well established example of a gas dissolving in a liquid when the temperature is more than the gas's critical temperature.

Comment: 1/ a gas is a component of gaseous phase, or part of mixed gas without mentioning the phase. 2/ There are sometimes disagreements when to call a gas vapour, but expression "vapour phase" is not used. 3/ The fact that you live is such an example. You do breathe oxygen, don't you ? What is its critical temperature ?

Comment: @Poutnik [1]So, in Henry's law , it is of no significance whether the undissolved gas above the liquid is vapour or not (means the temp. may be more or less than the gas's critical temperature)?   [2] I don't think there are any disagreements about whether a gas is vapour or not; it's termed a vapour if the gas is at a temperature lower than its critical temperature (src: Wikipedia).  [3] O2 is not a great example...most of it is transported by binding to haemoglobin and not simply dissolving in blood. [4]Thanks for such active replies to my querries :)

Comment: Calling gas a vapour or not is strongly context dependent and the boundary is fuzzy. CO2 in air is never called CO2 vapour, probably because you do not meet liquid CO2 at atmospheric conditions. Alternative approach is, gas is called vapour, if its boiling point at given pressure is above given temperature // Oxygen would not bind to haemoglobin, if did not previously dissolved in liquid. Fish breathe dissolved oxygen in water. Plus, you did hear about the diver keson disease, due releasing nitrogen bubbles in veins.

Comment: [1] Ok, agreed on O2 but what about this....{So, in Henry's law , it is of no significance whether the undissolved gas above the liquid is vapour or not (means the temp. may be more or less than the gas's critical temperature)? .....}

Comment: Yes, it does not depend on it. Or rather very indirectly. As high critical temperature often - not always - means high polarity , solubility and non ideal behaviour of the solution.